# Why do I get "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'format'" error?

Tags: python, database, sqlite

I am running this code to create a table and print its components.

```
import Proje_2

şarkı_listesi = Proje_2.Şarkı_listesi()

isim = input("İsim:")
sanatçı = input("Sanatçı:")
albüm = input("Albüm:")
prodüksiyon_şirketi = input("Prodüksiyon şirketi:")
şarkı_süresi = int(input("Şarkı süresi(sn):"))
        
yeni_şarkı = Proje_2.Şarkı(isim, sanatçı, albüm, prodüksiyon_şirketi, şarkı_süresi)
        
print("Şarkı ekleniyor")
şarkı_listesi.şarkı_ekle(yeni_şarkı,)
        
print("Şarkı eklendi")

şarkı_listesi.şarkıları_göster()
```

Also this is the module I am using:

```
import sqlite3

class Şarkı():
    def __init__(self,isim,sanatçı,albüm,prodüksiyon_şirketi,şarkı_süresi):
        self.isim = isim
        self.sanatçı = sanatçı
        self.albüm = albüm
        self.prodüksiyon_şirketi = prodüksiyon_şirketi
        self.şarkı_süresi = şarkı_süresi
    def __str__(self):
        print("Şarkı ismi: {}\nSanatçı: {}\nAlbüm: {}\nProdüksiyon şirketi:{}\nŞarkı süresi(saniye): {}").format(self.isim, self.sanatçı, self.albüm, self.prodüksiyon_şirketi, self.şarkı_süresi)

class Şarkı_listesi():
    def __init__(self):
        self.bağlantı_oluştur()
        
    def bağlantı_oluştur(self):
        self.bağlantı = sqlite3.connect("şarkı_listesi.db")
        self.cursor = self.bağlantı.cursor()
        
        sorgu = "Create Table if not exists şarkı_listesi (isim TEXT,sanatçı TEXT,albüm TEXT,prodüksiyon_şirketi TEXT,şarkı_süresi INT)"
        
        self.cursor.execute(sorgu)
        self.bağlantı.commit()
        
    def bağlantıyı_kes(self):
        self.bağlantı.close

    def şarkıları_göster(self):
        sorgu = "Select * from şarkı_listesi"
        şarkı_listesi = self.cursor.fetchall()
        self.cursor.execute(sorgu,)
        
        if (len(şarkı_listesi) == 0):
            print("Listenizde şarkı bulunmuyor")
            
        else:
            for i in şarkı_listesi:
                şarkı = Şarkı(i[0], i[1], i[2], i[3], i[4])
                print(şarkı)
                
    def şarkı_ekle(self,şarkı):
        sorgu = "Insert into şarkı_listesi Values(?,?,?,?,?)"
            
        self.cursor.execute(sorgu, (şarkı.isim,şarkı.sanatçı,şarkı.albüm,şarkı.prodüksiyon_şirketi,şarkı.şarkı_süresi))
        self.bağlantı.commit()
```

When I run the code, first it says "Listenizde şarkı blunmuyor" and if I add another "şarkı_listesi.şarkıları_göster()" function it says "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'format'" then locks the database. Why?

Answer (score 0):

[`format()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) is a method on the `str` class. You've chained it to the output of `print`, which is *always* `None`. Move the call to `format()` inside the `print` statement to properly chain it to your string:

```
def __str__(self):
    print("Şarkı ismi: {}\nSanatçı: {}\nAlbüm: {}\nProdüksiyon şirketi:{}\nŞarkı süresi(saniye): {}".format(self.isim, self.sanatçı, self.albüm, self.prodüksiyon_şirketi, self.şarkı_süresi))
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the `print` in the `__str__` method to a `return`. The **str** method will format the output, and the `print` in `şarkıları_göster` will print it.

Aside: It says  "Listenizde şarkı blunmuyor"` the first time because the fetchall() is before the execute(). I'm not sure if that was part of the "Why?"